# Error when connecting to XML file office add-in c#

Tags: c#, xml

I am working on a project with Microsoft office Excel add-in with Fisual Studio 2015 c#.

The Excel is supposed to have a button that, when it has been clicked, will bring all the data from a Remote XML file on an internal server.

However, I am getting this error while I am connecting:

> server response contain error

I used this code :

```
private const string utilityUrl = "http://bitreporting/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2fCockpits%2fOrgaCockpit%2fCockpit&rs%3aCommand=Render&rs:format=xml";
          XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
                xmlDoc.Load(utilityUrl );
                MessageBox.Show(xmlDoc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes[1] + "");
```

When I download the XML manually and access it from my computer then everything is okay.

Can anybody tell me what is the problem with this code?

Comment: This is just a guess, but there's a good chance you've got some characters in that string that aren't escaped, causing the URL to be wrong. Try adding @ in front of your string: @"http://...xml";

Comment: well, actually I already try it. the thing is that the URL is correct and when I access it using the browser it responed with the XML file. it is kind of strange. but I have no idea what is the problem and also it does not give me too many details

Comment: Doesn't it require **".com"** ? Can be wrong just a wonder.

Comment: one more details, it gave me the error 401. which means unathorized. but I cann access this like using all the browsers from my laptop

Comment: it is an internal server only for our company

Comment: `var doc = XDocument.Load("path");` try this. @SamySammour

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem, it was in the Authorization.

because the server is internal and prevent an external request so I have to use webclient.

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
wc.Proxy = null;
wc.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
string xml = wc.DownloadString(url);
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
MessageBox.Show(doc.FirstNode + "");
```